# Swift change position of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am adding a image view by code, and setting the image aspect fit to be ScaleAspectFit.

What I can't get to work is the top space/constraint of the image. I would like to have the image set at a specific space to the top while keeping the ScaleAspectFit.

When you swipe between the images the all have a different top position which looks odd.

My structure is page view controller > scroll view. In order to add zoom to the images.

code for adding the image:

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
imageView.url = imageFileName?.toURL()
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
```

And here is a print screen to show the problem. What I am trying to do is to always make the black space to the top have the same height of all images. So that they all have the same top space.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.ScaleAspectFit` you can use `.ScaleAspectFill` which guarantees that the image always completely fills the view. Then none of the image views will have uneven empty space at the top.

If you must have `.ScaleAspectFit` behavior, then you can calculate the "aspect fitting" frame of the image and set its frame manually so that it fits and is top aligned:

```
import AVFoundation
...
let aspectRatio = imageView.image.size.width / imageView.image.size.height
let aspectRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(aspectRatio, scrollView.bounds)
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, aspectRect.size.width, aspectRect.size.height)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried ScaleAspectFill first, but that made all images start of zoomed in. But your second solution did it :)

Comment: It worked good in obj-c but how do I implement that in swift?

Answer (score 0):

Add another UIView to the top section of your scroll view. Adjust it the height you want. Do layout constraints and it should work.